# Is this a valid proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected, i.e., $\mathbb{R}=A \cup B$, where $A,B$ are open sets that are disjoint.

$A$ is bounded above by each element of $B$, so $A$ must have a supremum, call it $x$. $x$ cannot be in $A$, since $A$ is open and we could take $B_\epsilon(x)$ and find an element $a \in  B_\epsilon(x)$ such that $a>x$, which means $x$ can't be the supremum of $A$.

Similarly, if $x \in B$, We can find $b \in B_\epsilon(x)$ such that $b<x$ and yet $b$ is still an upper bound for $A$, so thus again $x$ can't be the supremum of $A$.

Thus the supremum of $A$ can't exist, contradicting the fact that each nonempty set of real numbers bounded above has a supremum.

I really like this argument and I'm just wondering if everything I have here makes sense.

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Comment: Why should $A$ be bounded above by each element of $B$?

Comment: That was the part I was unsure about most. They are disjoint sets  so nothing in $A$ can ever be bigger than anything in $B$.

Comment: A quick adjustment will let you use the same type of argument. If $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, then for a given $a \in A$, one of the two sets $C = \{x \in B : x < a\}$ or $D = \{x \in B : x > a\}$ must be non-empty. Therefore looking at either the $\sup(C)$ or the $\inf(D)$ should let you make the same type argument.

Comment: What you can do to save this argument: There are $a\in A, b\in B$ and wLog $a<b$. Then the set $C=\{x\mid\emptyset\ne[a,x]\subseteq A\}$ is non-empty and bounded above by $b$, so it has a supremum $s$. By your reasoning this $s$ can neither belong to $A$ nor to $B$.

Answer (score 1):

It does not folow *immediately* that $A$ is bounded above by *each* element of $B$.

However, if we additionally assume that $A,B$ are both nonempty and let $a\in A$, $b\in B$ be arbitrary elements, we may assume wlog. that $a<b$. Then your argument should work with $x=\sup(A\cap[a,b])$

Comment: Why answering before the OP replies to a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that every interval of $\mathbb R$ is connected.  Remember: A subset $J$ is per def. an interval of $\mathbb R$ iff for any $a$, $b$ $\in J$ the segment $\{a+t(b-a)\mid t\in[0,1]\}\subset J$, i.e., if $a$ and $b$ belong to $J$, then all numbers between $a$ and $b$ belong to $J$.  Then realize that $\mathbb R$ is an interval of $\mathbb R$.